# Which person am I looking for (music-sheet)

Tags: music

Which person am I looking for?
[image: Music-Sheet]

Comment: Seems like a bass part of a song.

Comment: correct @KrisVanBael

Comment: What is the clef or key?

Comment: Based on accidentally, it must be treble clef,  and two sharps in the signature, putting the song in the key of D major.

Comment: I would guess Rick Astley

Comment: @SnySmartie not correct. I give it that: This really is hard und might not be THAT satisfying for everyone, but it is solvable with this sheet

Comment: I don't recognize the tune.